# Node JS - How to view progress when using Archiver (zip)

Tags: node.js, progress-bar, node-archiver

I already searched on the Web and I finded solutions using "entries".
But this solution is not fit when you have (for example) a very big file in folder containing may files.
The progress seams to be stopped while processing of the big file.

I really want the user to see the current processing.
So I thought to another solution.
Display the size of the compress file during the processing.

I know it's possible to use "createReadStream" to follow a file upload.
But how to follow the size of compress file....?

Comment: https://www.archiverjs.com/archiver#event:progress makes it seem like you can use .on('progress', function(progressData){    //use progress data here })

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The event 'progress' allows you to see 'totalBytes' and 'processedBytes', yes but...
But this event is fired when the processing of entry is finish.

So if you take my example with a folder containing a very big file in folder containing may files
During the processing of the big file, you have no information, just after.

Hoping to be clear in my explications